# Why isn't my timer in godot returning to 0?

Tags: game-physics, godot, gdscript

```
extends Node

onready var box_container: BoxContainer = $VBoxContainer
var stage = 0 setget on_stage_change
var timer = 0.0



func on_stage_change(new_value):
    if new_value > 5:
        stage = 5
    else:
        stage = new_value


func _process(delta):   
    if stage > 5:
        return
    var file: Dictionary = loadjson()
    handle_message(file, timer)
    if timer == 0.0:
        print("corrent")
    timer += delta
    
    

func handle_message(file: Dictionary, timer: float):
    #print(file)
    var json = file[String(stage)]
    
    if json["sender"] == "system":
        add_system_message(json["message"])
    elif json["sender"] == "boss":
        add_boss_message(json["message"], timer)
        print(timer) # is > 1
    else:
        print("currently not handled")
    
func add_boss_message(message: String, timer: float):
    #print(timer)
    var current_label = box_container.get_child(box_container.get_child_count()-1)
    if is_most_recent_message_typing() and timer > 1:
        current_label.text = message
        stage += 1
        timer = 0.0
        print(timer) #is zero
        #print(timer)
    elif not is_most_recent_message_typing():
        var label = Label.new()
        label.modulate = Color(1, 0, 0)
        label.text = "[typing]"
        box_container.add_child(label)
    print(timer) # is zero
        

func is_most_recent_message_typing():
    #timer = 0
    if box_container.get_child(box_container.get_child_count()-1).text == "[typing]":
        return true
    return false
    
func loadjson():
    var file: File = File.new()
    file.open("Messages.json", File.READ)
        
    var json_file = parse_json(file.get_as_text())
    #print(json_file)
    return json_file

func add_system_message(message: String):
    var label = Label.new()
    label.text = message
    label.modulate = Color(1, 0, 0)
    box_container.add_child(label)
    stage += 1
```

for some reason my timer never returns to zero, despite me setting it. I have tracked the execution of the program, and found out that the timer resets to > 1 after the add_boss_message is executed.

Could someone please tell me why the variable isn't returning to 0

Using the latest stable version of godot on steam

Comment: `timer` inside `add_boss_message` is a local variable. It is not the same as the member variable `timer` of your script class. Why did you pass it as an argument to your functions instead of working on the member directly?

Comment: @UnholySheep Thanks man I forgot I made it a global variable haha. I would accept your answer but you didn't put it in an answer

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[UnholySheep](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2878796/unholysheep) gave the answer in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72754785/why-isnt-my-timer-in-godot-returning-to-0/72754935#comment128508200_72754785):

> `timer` inside `add_boss_message` is a local variable. It is not the same as the member variable `timer` of your script class. Why did you pass it as an argument to your functions instead of working on the member directly?

Comment: I've converted your post here into something that you can accept. Note that it has (a) attribution - it says who posted it and links to the comment, (b) the text of the comment itself, in case the helpful comment is deleted, etc.